# VAR Variables in Array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USER_TABLE where `user` = 'user_name'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$user = $result['user'];
$password = $result['password'];

class SimpleAuth
{

    // The users List ('Login' => 'Password')
    var $users = array(
    'user1' => 'password1',      // want to replace it with variables $user and $password
    'user2' => 'password2',      // User 2
    'user3' => 'password3',      // User 3
    );
................
}
```

I am struggling with syntax on how to use variables $user and $password and where to put the mysql query in order to pass the value to these two variables.

EDITED: I would like to replace 'user1' and 'password1' with variables (i.e. $user, $password). AND before that, I would run a mysql query to get $user and $password from database. Once I change that to

```
$user => $passwords,
```

I get the follow error

> ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$user' (T_VARIABLE),
>   expecting ')'

Can someone help? Many many thanks in advance!

**P.S.** I don't know if I should include all codes. If so, please advise.

Comment: could you clarify, what do you want to do, and how exactly does mysql come in the picture?

Comment: That was a rather poor edit - it removed important information.

Comment: Sorry for my poor presentation. I have edited more information.

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen, it's a bit confusing but there is no "$user2" in the information above at all. Did you forget to add something to the question perhaps?

Comment: No, I created a table for a particular user1 with only one row. So the user can change the password from time to time. However, the user2 and user3 can remain plain text and stay inside the php so that the sysop which is I can still login.

Comment: Alexander, the $user2 was a typo. Sorry

Comment: remove keyword "var" in your define variable ,remove "," end of array value and remove this addation :)

Answer (score 2):

please code change to :

```
class SimpleAuth
{

    // The users List ('Login' => 'Password')
    // public , private , protected 
    // don't use keyword "var"

    public $users_1 = array(
                           $user => $password,             // User 1
                           'user2' => 'password2',         // User 2
                           'user3' => 'password3'       // User 3
    );

    //for define variable from value variable : this code

     public $users_2 = array(
                           ${$user} => ${$password},             // User 1
                           'user2' => 'password2',         // User 2
                           'user3' => 'password3'       // User 3
    );            

}
```

................
end of code or end of array remove "," and remove this addation :)

---

***Example :***

```
<?php
$k1 = "k1";
$v1 = "v1";

$arr_1 = array(
               ${$k1} => ${$v1},
               "k2"   => "v2",
               "k3"   => "v3"
       );
//or
$arr_2 = array(
               $k1 => $v1,
               "k2"   => "v2",
               "k3"   => "v3"
       );
var_dump($arr_1);
var_dump($arr_2);
?>
```

***Result :***

```
//$arr_1
array(3) { 
            ["k1"]=> string(2) "v1" 
            ["k2"]=> string(2) "v2" 
            ["k3"]=> string(2) "v3" 
}

//$arr_2
array(3) { 
            ["k1"]=> string(2) "v1" 
            ["k2"]=> string(2) "v2" 
            ["k3"]=> string(2) "v3" 
}
```

Comment: removing the comma doesn't help. And still get the same syntax error